# Database error in logcat

Tags: android

i am working on an application and it works fine but in log i can see the below mentioned error: PLease suggest what could be the reason behind this and how to fix this..
I have closed all the cursors and also closing the database connection after use.
PLease help...

12-02 17:16:48.500: ERROR/Database(388): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.my/databases/my.db' 
12-02 17:16:48.500: ERROR/Database(388): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-02 17:16:48.500: ERROR/Database(388): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
12-02 17:16:48.500: ERROR/Database(388): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
12-02 17:16:48.500: ERROR/Database(388): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)

Comment: Please note that I've changed the answer below. This time, it should be the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the database from your activity's `onDestroy` method. Assuming that you've written your application using a "database helper" class, as in some Android tutorials such as [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html), then this ought to work for you as-is. (Otherwise, just replace `mDbHelper.close()` with the appropriate call to close your database connection.)

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
// ...
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Angel: I'm afraid I was right not to trust that answer; I just saw the error again. I've replaced what I had written with an answer that I think is correct. If it works for you, please "accept". Thanks.